# Unable o create foreign key with the help of code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using the code below, but unable to create the foreign key.

```
USE project;
GO
ALTER TABLE Sale.TempSalesReason 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TempSale_SalesReason FOREIGN KEY (TempID) 
    REFERENCES Sale.SalesReason (SalesReasonID) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
;
GO
```

Comment: Error I am getting is: The specified schema name "Sales" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

Comment: And what's unclear about that error?

Comment: You show us code without the schemaname. Does the table belong to the schema "Sales" as in "Sales.Sale.TempSalesReason"? Are You aware what a schema is?

Comment: Your code above says "Sale" not "Sales".

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through the link below and check if you are able to create the foreign key relationships in SQL server.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx